# how to change background color in vaadin 14 with getStyle()

Tags: vaadin

I have tried changing the background color with getStyle() but it did not quite work, even though changing the color worked.

Heres my code:

```
public class HomeUi extends VerticalLayout {

    public HomeUi(){
        this.setSizeFull();
        HorizontalLayout back = new HorizontalLayout();
        back.setSizeFull();
        back.getStyle().set("background","red");
        back.getStyle().set("color","blue");
        back.add(new Paragraph("HELLO BEAUTIFUL WORLD!"));
        this.add(back);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with you setup. I tried you code and it works. Maybe you are having some CSS overriding your values or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
back.getStyle().set("background-color","red");
```

Comment: for some reason it does not work for me, I tried it on my computer in chrome and edge and on my phone in firefox, in all three cases the background was white, even though in the generated source code it says
`
{
            "node": 5,
            "type": "put",
            "key": "background-color",
            "feat": 12,
            "value": "red"
        },
`

Comment: January 2023: It DOES work, I just checked it with latest firefox

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it works as you expected.
I got red background with blue text.

```java
@Slf4j
@PageTitle("test")
@Route(value = "test", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout {

    public TestView() {
        this.setSizeFull();
        HorizontalLayout back = new HorizontalLayout();
        back.setSizeFull();
        back.getStyle().set("background","red");
        back.getStyle().set("color","blue");
        back.add(new Paragraph("HELLO BEAUTIFUL WORLD!"));
        this.add(back);
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I used Vaadin in compability mode.
I upgraded the Vaadin version to 23 and removed compability mode and then changing the color worked fine.